# Struts1 with IntelliJ IDE

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, integration, struts-1

I have developed struts1 application with Eclipse. I had to change my IDE into IntelliJ. I need to develop a new application integrating struts1 and Spring. I found some interesting tutorials from,

[struts-spring-integration-example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-spring-integration-example/)
 and [spring-and-struts-integration/](http://www.javacodebook.com/2013/07/26/spring-book-chapter-12-spring-and-struts-integration/3/)
Since above examples were developed using Eclipse IDE, I might wonder is there is any better (easy) way of doing it using Intellij .

Please mentioned any tutorials or better way to doing this.

Comment: Beware, Struts1 is now deprecated and no longer maintained ... Just look in [Struts official page](http://struts.apache.org/). Are you sure you want to use it for a *new* application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you try? I got Spring working in IntelliJ using Maven and copying other [working projects](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc). I hope that also can work for you. Configure Maven for IntelliJ, if you can get spring working with IntelliJ try make it work from the command prompt with maven + your app server (I can recommend jetty) and then you can open the Spring/Maven project in IntelliJ and it will work.